# php pregmatch date in string

Tags: php, date, get

Does anyone know how to preg match the following:

```
7th January 2017 - 29th December 2018
```

I looked at `preg_match` - not sure how to change it
so either getting 7th January 2017 AND 29th December 2018 Or the 
whole thing ? thanks

Comment: What language are you using? You should tag your post accordingly.

Comment: sorry i am using php

Answer (score 0):

sorry php...having not mastered preg_match I came up with :

```
$s='the seminar is on 23th January 2018 at the...';
$a=explode( " " , $s );
$months=array('january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december');
$i=0;
foreach( $ar_dates as $d ) {
    $d = strtolower( $d );
    if ( in_array(  $d , $months )) {
        $d1 = date_parse( $d );
        $mm = $d1['month'];
        if(isset($ar_dates[ $i-1]))  { $dd = $ar_dates[$i-1]; }  else { $dd=''; }
        if(isset($ar_dates[ $i+1])) { $yy = $ar_dates[$i+1]; } else { $yy='';  }
        $a_date = $yy . '-' . $mm . '-' . $dd;
    }
}
```